# Retrieve reformatted URL from webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-news

I am using the (deprecated, but still functional) GoogleNews API to search for news pertaining to certain stocks that I follow. The API returns the source and a GoogleNews link to the article, but I would prefer the direct link from the source. Is there a method to use the GoogleNews link and retrieve the link to the direct article?

For reference, the GoogleNews API might return: http://news.google.com/./articles/CAIiEB8taITanutbSbv39RsNMyMqGQgEKhAIACoHCAow4uzwCjCF3bsCMIrOrwM?uo=CAUieWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmJsb29tYmVyZy5jb20vbmV3cy9hcnRpY2xlcy8yMDIyLTAxLTEwL2NoaW5hLXMtY29uc3VtZXJzLXJpc2stZm9tby1hcy1lbGVjdHJpYy1jYXJzLXBvcHVsYXJpdHktc29hcnMta3k4bHNjczbSAQA&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen

but I would prefer: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-01-10/china-s-consumers-risk-fomo-as-electric-cars-popularity-soars-ky8lscs6

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Good answers require good questions - Please improve your question, code to reproduce and expected result should always be provided as text. Where do you stuck? - Take a minute and read also [ask]  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `requests` package:

```
import requests

url = 'http://news.google.com/...'

# Set cookie consentement and DON'T USER User-Agent
cookies = {'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20210720-07-p0.en+FX+410'}
response = requests.head(url, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=True)
print(response.history[-1].url)

# Output
https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-01-10/china-s-consumers-risk-fomo-as-electric-cars-popularity-soars-ky8lscs6
```